# Questions of Hyperspace of Compact Sets

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Let $K(X)$ the space of all non-empty compact subsets of $X$ equipped with the topology from the Hausdorff metric.

if $X$ is metrizable and $K_n\in K(X)$, $K_1 \supseteq K_2 \supseteq \ldots$. Then $\lim_n  K_n=\bigcap K_n$. In particular if $K_n$ is the union of the $2^{n}$  many closed intervals ocuurring in the n th step of the construccction of the Cantor ser $E_{\frac{1}{3}}$, $K_n \to E_{\frac{1}{3}}$.?

a suggestion for this exercise ? please.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You are taking limits in $K(X)$ but never told us what topology $K(X)$ has.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  $K_n$ is the union of $2^n$ many intervals as in the Cantor set construction, and you are asking if $\bigcap_n K_n$ equals the Cantor set?  Well, yes, it does; that is exactly the definition of the Cantor set.  Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I guess that the question is about convergence in the Vietoris topology.

Comment: This question appears to be Exercise 4.28 (p.27) of Kechris's _Classical Descriptive Set Theory_. If that is the case attribution should be given.

Comment: @joseph if you're using Kechris' text, then the previous page has an exercise that implies that if the upper limit and the lower limit coincide, then it equals the limit (if it's compact), and the intersection is indeed the upper and lower limit.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of Hausdorff metric I will use, starting from a metric space $(X,d)$, is $d_H(K_1, K_2) = \max(\sup_{x \in K_1} d(x, K_2), \sup_{x \in K_2} d(x, K_1))$.

So suppose $K = \cap_n K_n$, where $K_{n+1} \subseteq K_n$ for all $n$, and all $K_n$ are non-empty compact (so $K$ is too). For $x \in K$, $x \in K_n$ as well, so $d(x, K_n) = 0$, so $\sup_{x \in K} d(x, K_n) = 0$ for all $n$. This takes care of one term in the formula for $d_H(K, K_n)$. We see that in this case $d_H(K_n, K) = \sup_{x \in K_n} d(x,K)$.

Also, as $K_{n+1} \subseteq K_n$ for all $n$, we have that $d_H(K_{n+1},K) = \sup_{x \in K_{n+1}} d(x,K) \le \sup_{x \in K_n} d(x,K) = d_H(K_n, K)$, as the sup of a larger set can only be larger, so the sequence of distances  $d_H(K_n, K)$ is mononotonically decreasing, and positive, so assume $\lambda > 0$ would be its infimum; if $\lambda = 0$ we would be done, as in any metric space, $K_n \rightarrow K$ iff $d_H(K_n, K) \rightarrow 0$.

So pick $x_n \in K_n$ such that $d(x_n, K) \ge \frac{\lambda}{2} > 0$. Then as all $x_n$ are in the compact $K_0$, some subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ converges to some $x \in X$, and by the decreasingness of the $K_n$ one easily sees that $x \in K_n$ (as all terms of a tail of the subsequence are in $K_n$, which is closed), for all $n$, so $x \in K$ by definition. But as $y \rightarrow d(y,K)$ is continuous, this contradicts the fact that all $d(x_{n_k}, K) \ge {\lambda \over 2}$, while their limit has distance $0$ to $K$.

So indeed $d_H(K_n, K) \rightarrow 0$ and we are done with the statement.

So we have that if we have decreasing family $K_n$ of non-empty compact in the hyperspace (in the Vietoris topology or Hausdorff metric), the intersection is their topological limit.

The remark about the Cantor set is then an immediate consequence of this and the Cantor set's definition.